# Does Window 2003 standard server with IIS 6.0 support MVC 4?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, asp.net-mvc

I'm upgrating MVC 2.0 application to MVC 4.0. The MVC 2.0 is deployed on MS Window Server 2003 Standard x64 Edition Service Pack 2 with IIS 6.0

After upgrating the web application Can I deploy MVC 4 application on same server with same configuration. The reason I'm asking is I need to provide the requirement to infrastructure team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely is possible. You do require .NET 4.0 to be installed on the server though. Also, the application will have to be configured in IIS to work with .NET 4. [This](http://blog.binarymist.net/2011/10/24/getting-mvc-4-running-on-server-2003/) article goes through that process quite nicely, although the actual configuration really depends on how things are set up already.